# saving outputs of for loop to different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got rather simple problem, but I just can't wrap my head around solution.
I have lists of individual identificators of universities and individual names of universities

`iden = [60000308,60002049....so on]`

`uni = [MISIS12, NSU12... so on]`

I want to use them in for loop to retrieve data about publications of these universities and to save outputs to different DataFrames. I have retrieval code (I use pybliometrics and this works)

`df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(ScopusSearch("AF-ID( 60000308 )",date=2012, refresh=True, subscriber=False).results))[['subtypeDescription','publicationName','coverDisplayDate', 'source_id','citedby_count' ]]`

But I just don't get how to use it in a for loop to produce different DataFrames and also to name them by the names of universities?

Comment: Sadly, I know next to nothing about Panda and its Dataframe. For a pure Python the task doesn't look too complicated. I think it will help a bit if you add the tags `pandas` and `dataframe` to your question.